# Getting error when running command npm install cypress --save-dev

Tags: cypress

Getting below error when running command npm install cypress --save-dev

```
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;BrowserServers\chromedriver.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! cypress@4.12.1 postinstall: node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;BrowserServers\chromedriver.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@4.12.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-07T12_33_09_219Z-debug.log
```

NOTE : Have run npm-init and package.json is created

node -v
v12.18.3

npm -v
6.14.6

also have set NODE_HOME Env variable

Answer (score 0):

check you using Node.js 8 and above